# bootstrap search and filter input control

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I would like to build a search and filter user input field. One of the old bootstrap pages demonstrates exactly what I want but I've some trouble displaying the results.

[Bootstrap example page](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/dropdowns/)
The Search on top right side is what I'm looking for

I've extracted the elements required and built a simple form and here is the fiddle. The search result choices are not displayed at all. If I remove the dropdown-menu css class, the search results are displayed but they stay like that. I would like them to appear dynamically when I search for a matching text.

Also, how to display those results without pushing the controls below the results down.

```css
.bd-search-results {
  right: 0;
  display: block;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  font-size: 0.9rem;
}

.dropdown-menu {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  float: left;
  min-width: 10rem;
  margin: 0.125rem 0 0;
  color: #292b2c;
  text-align: left;
  list-style: none;
  background-color: #fff;
  background-clip: padding-box;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  border-radius: 0.25rem;
}

.dropdown-item {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 3px 1.5rem;
  clear: both;
  font-weight: 400;
  color: #292b2c;
  text-align: inherit;
  white-space: nowrap;
  background: 0 0;
  border: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-GJzZqFGwb1QTTN6wy59ffF1BuGJpLSa9DkKMp0DgiMDm4iYMj70gZWKYbI706tWS" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B0UglyR+jN6CkvvICOB2joaf5I4l3gm9GU6Hc1og6Ls7i6U/mkkaduKaBhlAXv9k" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<form class="bd-search hidden-sm-down">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="search-input" placeholder="Search..." autocomplete="off" />
  <div class="dropdown-menu bd-search-results" id="search-results">
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="/components/navbar/">Navbar</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="/components/navs/">Navs</a>
  </div>
  <br />
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="search-input" placeholder="Another text field..." autocomplete="off" />

</form>
```

An image explaining my question for more clarity.
[image]

Comment: What you want is JavaScript behavior, Bootstrap will give you CSS components with *some* JS features, but autocomplete functionality has to be implemented on your own AFAIK

Comment: yes, I know that rendering the items dynamically is javascript behavior but what i'm looking for is to adjust the way the results are displayed. Added an image for better understanding of my problem. I would like the choices to be displayed on top of the controls. In my image, the controls below server name and choices are pushed below. How to display the choices on top the remaining controls?

Comment: Can you share a fiddle replicating the image above? I'm pretty sure its an issue regarding a `position` property and your markup, if you can provide that so I can see it please do so

Comment: unfortunately, I cannot share the code. This UI is rendered in React using reactstrap library which extracts bootstrap elements. The same code snippet that I posted in my question can demonstrate my problem as well. However, you have to remove the dropdown-menu class from to display the choices and you can clearly see that next input control is pushed down which I want to prevent from happening.

Comment: I'm almost 100% sure that it has to do with a class there making the `position:absolute` not work as intended, if you see this basic example you'll see I basically just added the position and thats pretty much it, any further styling is up to you: https://codepen.io/IvanS95/pen/pGaWbM try commenting the `display: none` property and you'll see how it behaves

Answer (score -1):

I have had similar problems with bootstrap 4, and solved it with added the older bootstrap classes along with the new ones. You should try to add `class=“dropdown”` along with your current classes in your html tag.

Comment: Not a good idea using *old classes* expecting them to work between two different versions of the framework; the option you describe is precisely for *dropdown menus*, what OP wants I think is input field autocompletion